# How to make a program return to how it was loaded up? (vb)

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to code a VB program that when a button is pressed the system returns all text boxes, variables and forms to how they were when the program first loaded up.

I have managed to do it manually but there must be a faster and better way to do it. I'm being graded on this program any help is appreciated

Comment: How about launching a new instance of itself and shutting the current down?

Comment: [Application.Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.restart)

Comment: Specify a method as startup object instead of a form and open the form manually. This allows you to close it and reopen it at any time without leaving the application. Or use data binding. Then you can simply create a new data object and assign it to the data source to reset the form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.